# Why I can't open the Textfield when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm getting the `choice.toggle` so if it is a `Yes` it should be open, but the textarea is not opening, yet the `handleClick` says its open.

[image]

```
const handleClick = (choice) => {
  console.log(choice.toggle)
    if (choice.toggle === 'Yes') {
      console.log('Open')
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    }
};
```

```js
<label className="toggle-button" onClick={()=> handleClick(choice)}>
  <input className="toggle-button__state" type="radio" name="choice" value={choice.question_choices}
    onChange={handleChange} />
  <span className="toggle-button__text">{choice.toggle}</span>
</label>
{isOpen && choice.toggle === 'Yes' &&
<input type="text" style={{height: '200px' , width: '200px' }} name="text-field" />
}
```

Comment: in `handleClick` try to console the `choice` object and `isOpen` state

Comment: Add the handleChange code and states declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```js
setIsOpen(!isOpen);
```

with:

```js
setIsOpen(prevState => !prevState);
```